# Why can't the content in oj be displayed using oj[0]...oj[2]...oj[x]?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a basic webpage created using HTML.

I have used javascript in this. I have passed on the content of html element `h1` to `oj` using `getElementById`?

So `oj` should be an array (I read it in an online tutorial)?
Then why doesnt `oj[0]` print the content in the array?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello! Welcome to the world of Programing!</title>
    <script>
        alert("Welcome,Your activities are being watched!");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>

    <section  style="color:#FF0000" align="center" valign="middle">
        <p>
            <h1>1</h1>
            Come on in!Welcome!
        </P>
        <img src="b.jpg"> </img>
    </section>

    <section align="center">
        <h3> LOG IN </h3>
        <form action="http://www.sololearn.com" method="Post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
            Name: <br/>
            <input type="text" name="name"/> <br> </br>
            Email id: <br/>
            <input type="email" name="email"/> </br>
            Password: <br/>
            <input type="password" name"password" id="learnhtml"/> <br/>
            <a href="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=GNUnVpzID6jv8weZvajABg&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=forgot+password" target="_blank" > forgot password? </a> <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </form>
    </section>

    <script>
        var oj=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        var oja=oj[0]; 
        /*why am I not able to display the array using the above statement?*/
        alert(oja);
    </script> 
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: oj[0] is the first element of the array, oj is the array

Comment: and it does print that oja is an htmlelement

Comment: In your description you say that you use `getElementById` but the code that you show uses `getElementsByTagName`. Which is it actually?

Comment: getElementsByTagName
Which one creates an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have used javascript in this. I have passed on the content of html element h1 to oj using getElementById?

No. You have created an array of DOM objects. You can take their HTML content (the code/text inside) with `element.innerHTML`

```js
var oj=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var oja=oj[0].innerHTML; 
alert(oja);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I got it now!